# Is it okay to return an NSUInteger from tableView:numberOfRowsInSection?

Tags: ios, uitableview, casting

I am working on a simple Table View iOS application, and I want to display a cell for each entry in an NSMutableDictionary. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [myDict count];
}
```

It is my understanding that the count method of an NSMutableDictionary returns an NSUInteger. Will there ever be any issues that I need to watch out for using the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there will not be any issues since count is always a 0 or greater number, it is ok for it to return an unsigned integer.

Comment: Strictly speaking there could be an issue in the case where the [myDict count] exceeds NSIntegerMin/LONG_MAX, but in practice as you say it's not going to be an issue.  What I don't understand is why numberOfRowsInSection doesn't use NSUInteger in the first place (i.e. when would this ever want to return a negative number?).

Comment: @NicholasHarlen To my knowledge there is no reason to return a negative number, my guess is that Apple made it a NSInteger because at the time they though returning a negative number might be meaningful in a future implementation somehow.